# How prevent react-router refresh on goBack()?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history, browser-history

I use `BrowserRouter` from `react-router` for my app navigation, but on back is the problem. 
Should I use `StaticRouter`?

**My code:**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
...
<Router history={history}  forceRefresh={false}>
    ...
```

Comment: What problem do you have? There shouldnt be any problem with BrowserRouter. If you are navigating using `import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'` it should not reload full application on back button in the browser.

Comment: I use `Link`, but on go back component re-mount again. @TomasBruckner

Comment: Does goind back invokes `componentDidMount` again?

Comment: Yes, `componentDidMount` called again @SultanH.

Comment: can you provide a snap of what component's lifecycle methods you are using, all of them, please?

Comment: Sure, just `componentWillUnmount` & `componentDidMount`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough on this, I wanted to what's in them.